# Specifying the SSL endpoint for Heroku Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have two Heroku app tiers (a production and a staging app)

My DNS is configured to point to either, depending on the subdomain.

- `*.example.co` -> `app-production`
- `*.staging.example.co` - > `app-staging`

#### SSL

SSL add on is enabled for both. The same exact SSL wildcard certificate is uploaded to both.

```
> heroku certs --remote production
Endpoint                      Common Name(s)            Expires               Trusted
----------------------------  ------------------------  --------------------  -------
tokushima-XXXX.herokussl.com  *.example.co, example.co  2018-10-10 00:00 UTC  True


> heroku certs --remote staging
Endpoint                      Common Name(s)            Expires               Trusted
----------------------------  ------------------------  --------------------  -------
hiroshima-XXXX.herokussl.com  *.example.co, example.co  2018-10-10 00:00 UTC  True
```

#### Domains

Each has the corresponding domains also configured in Heroku

```
> heroku domains --remote production

=== app-production Custom Domains
Domain Name                    DNS Target
-----------------------------  -------------------------------------
*.example.co                   tokushima-XXXX.herokussl.com
example.co                     tokushima-XXXX.herokussl.com


> heroku domains --remote staging

=== app-staging Custom Domains
Domain Name           DNS Target
--------------------  ------------------------
*.staging.example.co  app-staging.herokuapp.com   <-- should this be the SSL endpoint?
```

#### Question

All the above works fine in terms of routing.

- `foo.example.co` visits my production app
- `foo.staging.example.co` visits my staging app

However **on staging, SSL does not work. I get a "certificate untrusted" error, even though it's the same certificate.**

I strongly suspect it's because when configuring the Staging Domains, the DNS target should be an SSL endpoint, not the direct heroku app URL.

But I have no way to edit that. If I do

```
> heroku domains:add *.staging.example.co --remote staging
```

It automatically adds the DNS target for me. On Prod it automatically added the SSL endpoint.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how ssl wildcard certificates behave: a certificate for *.example.com is valid for foo.example.com but not bar.foo.example.com.

This is specified in [rfc 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818), which says

> Names may contain the wildcard
> character * which is considered to match any single domain name
> component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
> not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com

Comment: Ah I see. So it appears there's no real way around it, unless I were to buy ANOTHER wild card cert for `*.staging.example.co`, right? Or since it's staging, I could generate a self-signed certificate too. But would that solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Self signed cert would work (once you've told the browser to trust it) and you can also by certificates valid for multiple domain names (you have to supply the full list when you generate the certificate)